# Transform only the first element of a Scala list

Tags: list, scala, dictionary

Is there a way to transform only the first element of a list without doing something super hacky like:

```
val head = l1.head
val tail = l1.tail
val l2   = change(head) :: tail
```

`updated()` looks like it could work, but isn't much of an improvement:

```
val head = l1.head
val l2   = l.update(0, change(head))
```

I'd love something like:

```
val l2   = l1.updateHead(change(_))
```

Is there anything like that?

Comment: is `val l2 = change(l1.head) :: l1.tail` really "super hacky"?

Comment: Maybe not, though everyone suggested lots of alternatives that look nicer to me. I think Robert's pattern matching approach is the simplest.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you could try using pattern matching

```
val l2 = l1 match{
    case Nil   => Nil
    case x::xs => change(x)::xs
}
```

That way you don't have to worry if `head` actually returns an element

Comment: Pattern matching rocks! Nice one.

Answer (score 9):

You are making your life much harder by introducing variables at every opportunity.  Don't do it!

Both of the options you listed are fairly clean if you don't introduce temporary variables:

```
val l2 = change(l.head) :: l.tail
val l2 = l.update(0, change(l.head))
```

Neither is entirely safe on empty lists, but

```
val l2 = l.take(1).map(change) ::: l.drop(1)
```

is.

You also are always free to enrich list with your own method, however:

```
class ReheadableList[A](xs: List[A]) {
  def rehead[B >: A](f: A => B) = xs.take(1).map(f) ::: xs.drop(1)
}
implicit def lists_can_be_reheaded[A](xs: List[A]) = new ReheadableList(xs)
```

(edit--changed to avoid errors with empty lists).  Now you can just

```
val l2 = l.rehead(change)
```

Answer (score 5):

Using partial lenses ([described in this paper](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7810909/media/doc/lenses.pdf)), you can write something like:

```
listHeadLens.set(list, newValue)
```

where `listHeadLens` is defined as:

```
def listHeadLens[A] = new PartialLens[List[A], A] {
  def apply: List[A] => Option[CoState[A, List[A]]] = {
    case Nil => None
    case x :: xs => Some(CoState(x, _ :: xs))
  }
}
```

I think partial lenses will be making their way to Scalaz 7. I am not sure though.

Answer (score 3):

There are probably a LOT of ways to do this. Below is a Scala REPL session showing one version

```
scala> val change = (x: Int) => x*2
change: Int => Int = <function1>

scala> val l = List(1,2,3)
l: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> l.headOption.map( x => change(x) :: l.drop(1) ).getOrElse(Nil)
res3: List[Int] = List(2, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this.

```
val list = List("1","2","3")
def change(str : String ) = Some("x")

val nlist = (list.headOption.flatMap(change(_)).toList ::: list.tail)
```

in the console.

```
scala> val list = List("1","2","3")
list: List[java.lang.String] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> def change(str : String ) = Some("x")
change: (str: String)Some[java.lang.String]

scala> val nlist = (list.headOption.flatMap(change(_)).toList ::: list.tail)          
nlist: List[java.lang.String] = List(x, 2, 3)
```