# Transform only the last element of a Scala list

Tags: scala

Is it possible to transform only the last element of a Scala list similar to this thread ?- [Transform only the first element of a Scala list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588255/transform-only-the-first-element-of-a-scala-list)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Another similar way is:

```
l match{
  case Nil            => Nil
  case xs :+ y => xs :+ change(y)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
val l2 = l1.dropRight(1) :+ change(l1.last)
```

Having said that, remember that Lists are a good data structure for accessing its head (and operate upon its tail), but very inefficient for random and direct access. If you need to be accessing the last element, it would be much more efficient to use direct access structures such as Arrays or Vectors.

Comment: This iterate through same list twice.

Comment: It's actually 3 times, because of the insertion to the last position. I'm already highlighting that using lists for this is not optimal at all.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for something like:
`list.init :+ changes(list.last)`
But example was provided by @mfirry will work faster and safely.
For the good performance you can use **Vector** instead of **List**.

Answer (score 0):

Version (adapted from the accepted answer in linked question) that only iterates through the list twice. And is obvious :)

```
val l2 = (l1.reverse match{
  case Nil   => Nil
  case x::xs => change(x)::xs
}).reverse
```

It's not possible to do better than iterating twice if you have an immutable list. Once to find the element at the end, and the second to replace it with the changed one

Answer (score 0):

slightly more generic version (still accepting only lists in its input)

```
  def mutateLast[A, R](l: List[A])(f: A => A)(implicit cb: CanBuildFrom[List[A], A, R]): R = {
    val builder = cb(l)

    @annotation.tailrec
    def loop(l: List[A]): R = l match {
      case Nil => builder.result()
      case h :: Nil =>
        builder += f(h)
        builder.result()
      case h :: t =>
        builder += h
        loop(t)
    }

    loop(l)
  }

  val l = List(1, 2, 3)
  val mutated = mutateLast(l)(x => x * 2)
  println(mutated)
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Must admit, this code for `List` is rather inefficient. `splitAt` function has complexity `O(n)`... But the same complexity has `.last` function. Assume to get better performance you should use some indexed collections instead of list.

```
  l.splitAt(l.size - 1) match {
    case (l1, l2) => l1 ::: l2.map(modify(_))
  }
```